# Updating local notification BadgeNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to show Today's date with the application badge number, this date should be updated when the application fires a Local Notification, but the problem is the local notification does not update the date ! and shows only date of the day on which my project was created ! here is my code :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

[self notification];

}

    - (void) notification  {


        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];    
        NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit| NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate: now];

        [componentsForFireDate year];
        [componentsForFireDate month];
        [componentsForFireDate day];
        [componentsForFireDate setHour:1];
        [componentsForFireDate setMinute:2];
        [componentsForFireDate setSecond:1];

        NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForFireDate];

                UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
                notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification;
                notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];                    notification.repeatInterval= NSDayCalendarUnit; 


                NSString *date = [self showGregorianFullDate];

                notification.alertAction = @"View";
                notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


        //updating badge number :

                NSCalendar* Calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
                NSDateComponents *Components = [Calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit )fromDate:[NSDate date]];

                int a = [Components day];
                notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = a; 

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

    }
```

Comment: It has to show you the date,when you executed this code,i mean,scheduled the notification.Maybe,you only scheduled it once,at that time?

Comment: the notification fires every day which should update the date ! , I scheduled the notification every 25 Hours ! to get the current date

Comment: Did you find a solution plz? I want to achieve the same think in some app .. thanks

Comment: When you say "I scheduled the notification every 25 Hours ! to get the current date" - I hope not.

Answer (score 1):

Do you only schedule this one notification? When notifications fire they don't get to run any code. If your app is open you can handle the notification, and if the user takes action on your notification you are again given a chance to handle it.

This notification is programmed to set the badge number to a certain day number. That number is a fixed number. It won't change automatically when the notification has been fired.

The application badge is designed to show a number of unhandled notifications ([as per the Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html)) and so may not be the best place to show a date. Also if you look at the [app store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) any app which uses system provided items in a way not described in the Human interface Guidelines could be rejected from the app store.

If you continue down this path then you may want to look at the [Local Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html). It shows each app can have 64 local notifications scheduled, and that you would need to schedule one every day to update the badge number to the next day. This means that if the user doesn't open your app for 65 days the badge number will be wrong, and you would also have no local notifications left for user alerts.

Answer (score -1):

Just get the day from `componentsForFireDate` for your `notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber`, just like this...

```
//updating badge number :
        int a = [componentsForFireDate day];
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = a;
```

The thing is that `applicationIconBadgeNumber` has to be pre-determined at the time you create the notification. If you get the day from `[NSDate date]`, it will show the day you create the notification not the day that the notification fires.